Kitty terminal: How can I attach to a zellij session upon starting up Kitty
I want zellij attach -c to run once Kitty is loaded up. I tried adding startup_session launch.conf to my config file, and writing kitty @ send-text "zellij attach -c" in launch.conf as well as launch sh -c "zellij attach -c" but neither works.

I got a solution here. I wrote in launch.conf:
launch zellij attach -c


Did you get it working with adding
launch zellij attach -c to your ~/.config/kitty/launch.conf?
For me, I added it to a ~/.config/kitty/launch.conf file and it did not work.
Is there a way you could share the contents of your ~/.config/kitty directory or do you have an idea of any additional changes I have to make (e.g add something to ~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf)?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
